# OnMouse enter add opacity transition of image

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation, hover

I have two images one laying right on top of another. I figured out how to show the image onMouse Enter but can't seem to figure out where to call the css transition property. Basically I'm trying to add a nice smooth transition of the showed image once the mouse hover over it. For now all I have is to set the display to 'block'  once the mouse enter but the experience of the image showing is abrupt. Please help

Image one that is showed first

```
const imageOne = {
backgroundImage: "url('/images/h2.png')",
backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
backgroundSize: 'cover',
backgroundPosition: 'center',
height: 400,
width: '100%',
position: 'relative',
zIndex: 1,
borderRadius: 5,
border: 'solid black 2px'
```

}

Image two that is shown when mouse hovers

```
    .overlay-image-1 {
  background-image: url("/images/h1.png");
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity:1;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
    z-index:2;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Actual components

```
<Grid 
    onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
    onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
    style={imageOne}>
        <div style={{display: hover ? 'block' : ''}} 
        className='overlay-image-1'>
        </div>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: use only opacity, and set css: transition: opacity 1s;

Comment: hmmm I've applied that the overlay-image-1 and still not effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS transitions wont work with display:none / display:block attributes, try:

visibility: hidden; & visibility: visible; for transitions to work properly.

to enabling the transition, simply set the opacity: 0; for visibility:hidden; and opacity:1; for visibility: visible;

Comment: Gotcha, and i've tried adding the transition to the  overlay-image-1 but no effect, do you have a suggestion as to where to add the transition property after the visibility is updated?

Comment: to enabling the transition, simply set the opacity: 0; for visibility:hidden; and opacity:1; for visibility: visible;

Comment: Gotcha! What I actually just did now is removed the visibility property and just used opacity: 0 on the image. Then applied opacity: 1 for the true statement when the image is hovered over. We got there together ahha thanks!

Comment: Great!! glad to hear that! If possible, can you please select it as a correct answer?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).